# Extracting counties and MSAs from state-county-MSA character variable

Tags: r, string, split

I have state, county and MSA names in a single string variable *states_county_MSA*, and I want to split them to create three distinct variables - *states*, *county* and *MSAs*.

```
tail(df$states_county_MSA,n=10)
 [1] "Iowa Polk Des Moines"                          
 [2] "Mississippi Hinds Jackson"                     
 [3] "Georgia Richmond Augusta-Richmond"             
 [4] "Ohio Mahoning Youngstown-Warren-Boardman"      
 [5] "Pennsylvania Lackawanna Scranton--Wilkes-Barre"
 [6] "Pennsylvania Dauphin Harrisburg-Carlisle"      
 [7] "Florida Brevard Palm Bay-Melbourne-Titusville" 
 [8] "Utah Utah Provo-Orem"                          
 [9] "Tennessee Hamilton Chattanooga"                
[10] "North Carolina Durham Durham"
```

Modifying the solution by @jared_mamrot to a similar question (splitting *state-county* variable into *state* and *county* distinct variables posted below ; full problem here for reference - [Extracting states and counties from state-county character variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71489701/extracting-states-and-counties-from-state-county-character-variable) ), I can split the *states_county_MSA* variable into two variables - *states* and *county-MSA* variable.

```
library(tidyverse)

states_county_names_df <- data.frame(states_county = c(
  "California San Francisco",                
  "New York Bronx",                                                    
  "Illinois Cook",                            
  "Massachusetts Suffolk",                    
  "District of Columbia District of Columbia"
  )
)

data(state)

states_inc_Columbia <- c(state.name, "District of Columbia")

states_county_names_df %>%
  mutate(state = str_extract(states_county, paste(states_inc_Columbia, collapse = "|")),
         county = str_remove(states_county, paste(states_inc_Columbia, collapse = "|")))
```

However, in this scenario, I am not able to decompose *states_county_MSA* further as I cannot find a function for county or MSA names.  Not able to get *county.names* function to work, and  tried using *tigiris*, *censusapi* and *maps* package but was unable to generate a vector of county names in US for the string split/extract command).

```
> data(county.names)
Warning in data(county.names) : data set ‘county.names’ not found
```

I was thinking of using the *word* function but names of MSAs are not standard either (one or more words).

Would anyone know a way to split the *county-MSA* in an efficient manner ?

EDIT - Data with (space) delimiter {county, state, MSA, MSA population, month, year}.

```
 [1] "Virginia         Richmond           Richmond                                1,210,063    8         2014"
 [2] "Louisiana        Orleans            New Orleans-Metairie-Kenner             1,195,794"                  
 [3] "North Carolina   Wake               Raleigh-Cary                            1,137,346     6        2014"
 [4] "New York         Erie               Buffalo-Niagara Falls                   1,135,342"                  
 [5] "Alabama          Jefferson          Birmingham-Hoover                       1,129,034"                  
 [6] "Utah             Salt Lake          Salt Lake City                          1,091,432     5        2014"
 [7] "New York         Monroe             Rochester                               1,080,082"                  
 [8] "Michigan         Kent               Grand Rapids-Wyoming                      989,205     7        2014"
 [9] "Arizona          Pima               Tucson                                    981,935    10        2013"
[10] "Hawaii           Honolulu           Honolulu                                  956,336     8        2013"
```

Comment: It certainly will be difficult to do this when there are no delimiters in your text field. Why is the original data like this?  Isn't it possible to get the data with a delimiter (other than space) between the three fields? Surely this data is available.

Comment: @G5W - I added the data with space delimters.  I imported it from a pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
data <- tibble::tribble(~state_county_msa,
                "Iowa Polk Des Moines"                          ,
                "Mississippi Hinds Jackson"                     ,
                "Georgia Richmond Augusta-Richmond"             ,
                "Ohio Mahoning Youngstown-Warren-Boardman"      ,
                "Pennsylvania Lackawanna Scranton--Wilkes-Barre",
                "Pennsylvania Dauphin Harrisburg-Carlisle"      ,
                "Florida Brevard Palm Bay-Melbourne-Titusville" ,
                "Utah Utah Provo-Orem"                          ,
                "Tennessee Hamilton Chattanooga"                ,
                "North Carolina Durham Durham")

state_county <- ggplot2::map_data("county") %>% 
  select(state = region,
         county = subregion) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),str_to_title)) %>% 
  unite(state_county, c("state","county"), sep = " ", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  distinct(state_county, .keep_all = TRUE)

state_county_string <- paste(state_county$state_county, collapse = "|")

data %>%
  mutate(state_county = str_extract(state_county_msa, state_county_string),
         msa = str_trim(str_remove(state_county_msa, state_county_string))) %>% 
  left_join(state_county, by = "state_county") %>% 
  select(state, county, msa)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   state          county     msa                          
   <chr>          <chr>      <chr>                        
 1 Iowa           Polk       Des Moines                   
 2 Mississippi    Hinds      Jackson                      
 3 Georgia        Richmond   Augusta-Richmond             
 4 Ohio           Mahoning   Youngstown-Warren-Boardman   
 5 Pennsylvania   Lackawanna Scranton--Wilkes-Barre       
 6 Pennsylvania   Dauphin    Harrisburg-Carlisle          
 7 Florida        Brevard    Palm Bay-Melbourne-Titusville
 8 Utah           Utah       Provo-Orem                   
 9 Tennessee      Hamilton   Chattanooga                  
10 North Carolina Durham     Durham
```

Comment: This works great @Matias1905.  However, is there a way to create the tibble without pasting the names of all areas / each observation ?